# How can I decode an IR signal that I get from a input GPIO in C#?

Tags: c#

How can I decode an IR signal that I get from a input GPIO in C#?

```
IR_Pin = gpio.OpenPin(PIN_Number);

if (IR_Pin.IsDriveModeSupported(GpioPinDriveMode.InputPullDown))
    IR_Pin.SetDriveMode(GpioPinDriveMode.InputPullDown);
else
    IR_Pin.SetDriveMode(GpioPinDriveMode.Input);

IR_Pin.ValueChanged += IR_Pin_ValueChanged;

private void IR_Pin_ValueChanged(GpioPin sender, GpioPinValueChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Edge == GpioPinEdge.FallingEdge)
    {
        }
}
```

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Well... what is the specific IR device, and what does it say it gives you?

Comment: I didn't try something like that in the recent times, but I think you'll have hard time making it working. C# / .Net aren't a realtime framework, and decoding an IR protocol requires almost certainly a precise measure of the interval between edges.

Comment: I am using windows IOT so real time processing shouldn't be a problem. I also think I'm going to have a hard time making it work but I think together we will get far.

Comment: Is it really C#? Or maybe C/C+ on a raspberry pie? I assume you are using some frameworks, I suggest you add tags to get the proper attention